# jQuery: Extract inner and outter string from object[property] string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form element that has the attribute ;

```
name="object[property]"
```

I want to extract the string values of object and property separately. Like using a regex to capture group, where group 1 is the value "object" and group 2 is the value "property".

How do I get this?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to do this with `/(.+?)\[(.+?)\]/`. This regex will match any string followed by any other string wrapped in square braces. It may produce unexpected results if there are more than one pair of square braces. `match` returns an array with the original string and all matched groups.

For example, with

```
var example = "test[value]".match(/(.+?)\[(.+?)\]/);
```

example would have value of `[ "test[value]", "test", "value" ]`

So `example[1]` is the object name and `example[2]` is the property string